In Power Query, how do I calculate total time worked over multiple days based on work shift patterns and excluding weekends?
Hello world of Stack Overflow. Thank you for your attention. I have 2 tables with the following data in Power Query, shown below.
Table 1: Shift Patterns



Day
Early Start Time
Early End Time
Late Start Time
Late End Time
Total Work Hours




Mon
07:30:00
15:15:00
15:10:00
22:10:00
14.67


Tue
07:30:00
15:15:00
15:10:00
22:10:00
14.67


Wed
07:30:00
15:15:00
15:10:00
22:10:00
14.67


Thu
07:30:00
15:15:00
15:10:00
22:10:00
14.67


Fri
07:00:00
13:00:00
12:55:00
18:55:00
11.92



Table 2: Work Processes



Process
Start DateTime
Start Day
End DateTime
End Day
Process Duration Hours (expected result)




1
03-Jun-2024 10:30:00
Mon
07-Jun-2024 18:25:00
Fri
67.10


2
04-Jun-2024 11:00:00
Tue
11-Jun-2024 10:00:00
Tue
69.60


3
05-Jun-2024 11:55:00
Wed
05-Jun-2024 22:10:00
Wed
10.25


4
06-Jun-2024 14:00:00
Thu
06-Jun-2024 14:00:01
Thu
0.00028


5
01-Nov-2021 23:38:59
Mon
02-Nov-2021 00:35:51
Tue
0.95



I need a Power Query formula that calculates Process Duration Hours in Table 2, which takes the shift hours from Table 1 and overtime into account. There are no shifts or overtime on weekends or public holidays. For example, in Table 2:

Process 1: Duration = Hours put into Process during work times from Mon 03-Jun to Fri 07-Jun
= Mon hours (10:30:00 to 22:10:00) 11.67 + Tue hours (full day) 14.67 + Wed hours (full day) 14.67 + Thu hours (full day) 14.67 + Fri hours (07:00:00 to 17:40:00) 11.42
= 67.10 hours

Process 2: Duration = Hours put into Process during work times from Tue 04-Jun to Tue 11-Jun
= Tue hours (11:00:00 to 22:10:00) 11.17 + Wed hours (full day) 14.67 + Thu hours (full day) 14.67 + Fri hours (full day) 11.92 + Mon hours (full day) 14.67 + Tue hours (07:30:00 to 10:00:00) 2.50
= 69.60 hours

Process 3: Duration = Hours put into Process during work times on Wed 05-Jun
= (11:55:00 to 22:10:00)
= 10.25 hours

Process 4: Duration = Hours put into Process during work times on Thu 06-Jun
= (14:00:00 to 14:00:01)
= 0.00028 hours

Process 5: Duration = Hours put into Process during overtime (outside shift hours) from Mon 01-Nov to Tue 02-Nov
= (23:38:59 to 00:35:51)
= 0.95 hours


(All values above rounded up for simplicity)
I have tried to hard code it and used various if/else statements, but nothing is producing accurate and repeatable results I need, no matter what the input from Table 2 is. Assume data format will always be correct and nulls are not allowed.
Any help will be immensely appreciated! Thank you <3

Examining your Expected Results, it appears that you are double counting the five (5) minutes of time worked between Late Start Time and Early End Time if some is working during that time. Is that your intent?

No that is not my intent, the 5 minutes overlap must not be double counted. Thank you for pointing this out!

Powerquery code for Work Processes table
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Process", Int64.Type}, {"Start DateTime", type datetime}, {"Start Day", type text}, {"End DateTime", type datetime}, {"End Day", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "date", each {Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From([Start DateTime]),1)..Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From([End DateTime]),1)}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "date"),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "day", each Text.Start(Date.DayOfWeekName([date], "en-US"),3),type text),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom1", {"day"}, #"Shift Patterns", {"Day"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Early Start Time", "Late End Time", "Total Work Hours"}, {"Early Start Time", "Late End Time", "Total Work Hours"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Table2", each ([Early Start Time] <> null)),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "duration", each 
    if Time.From([Start DateTime]) > Time.From ([Late End Time]) and Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From([Start DateTime]),1) = Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From([date]),1)  // start after end time -- you are working overtime
    then Duration.TotalHours(#time(23,59,59)-Time.From([Start DateTime])) else 
    if Time.From([End DateTime]) < Time.From ([Early Start Time])  // start before start  time -- you are working overtime
    then Duration.TotalHours(Time.From([End DateTime])-#time(0,0,0)) else 
    if Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From([Start DateTime]),1) = Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From([End DateTime]),1)  // end date = start date
    then Duration.TotalHours(Time.From(Time.From([End DateTime]))-Time.From([Start DateTime])) else 
    if Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From([End DateTime]),1) = Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From([date]),1)  // last date of multiple dates
    then Duration.TotalHours(Time.From(Time.From([End DateTime]))-Time.From([Early Start Time])) else 
    if Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From([Start DateTime]),1) = Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From([date]),1)  // first date of multiple dates
    then Duration.TotalHours(Time.From(Time.From([Late End Time]))-Time.From([Start DateTime])) else 
    [Total Work Hours]),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom2", {"Process", "Start DateTime", "Start Day", "End DateTime", "End Day"}, {{"duration", each List.Sum([duration]), type number}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"



My time math is incorrect, you are right! Sorry for the confusion.
Thank you for the post. I tried your query, but it seems to return incorrect values if the actual Process duration is very small, such as in seconds. For example, if Start DateTime = 21/Oct/2021 10:37:37, End DateTime = 21/Oct/2021 10:37:38, the Duration result returns 11.53975194. Correct Duration is 0.000277 recurring (1 sec in hours).

Thank you very much! I have edited my original question to correct the mistakes you had kindly pointed out. Your amended code seems to be working. However, when there are instances of the Process Start/End DateTime being outside the ranges in the Shift Patterns table, the Duration output returns negative values. These are situations when engineers started work earlier or stayed longer than expected (overtime) to complete tasks. Can the code be modified to account for this somehow?

For example: if Start DateTime = (Mon) 01/11/2021 23:38:59, End DateTime = (Tue) 02/11/2021 00:35:51;  Mon Duration = -1.483120278, Tue Duration = -6.902494444. Expected total Duration = 0.947777778.

Original question now amended to include this scenario. Thank you!

Tyvm <3 will do!
